# JavaScript class method not reflecting field values

Tags: javascript

In the following code, I would expect `printHello` to be called twice (once from `go()` and once from `runTask()`):

```
class Hello {
  task = undefined;

  runTask() {
    console.log("Task is", this.task);
    this.task();
  }
  
  printHello() { 
    console.log("Hello"); 
  }
  
  go() {
    this.task = this.printHello;
    console.log("Set task to", this.task);
    setTimeout(this.runTask, 0); // Fails
    // setTimeout(() => this.runTask(), 0); // Works
  }
};

const hello = new Hello();
hello.go(); // Says `this.task` is undefined, but then...
hello.runTask(); // ... running it manually works fine
```

In my mind:

- I create an instance of the class
- Then calling `go()`

  - Sets the `task` field/property on that instance to `printHello`
  - Sets up a request to `runTask` after the timeout

I would expect that `runTask` would be called with `task` set to `printHello`, but it's actually `undefined` in the `setTimeout` call. However, if I just call `runTask` directly on my `hello` instance it works fine. Also, if I replace the `setTimeout` call with a lambda it works fine.

It seems clear it's a stale closure type of issue, I just don't have a great mental model or rulebook that would prevent me from writing code like this in the future and then be perplexed about why it wasn't working.

I was thinking that `this` would be captured when passing `runTask`, which should then point to a valid task, but that's not the case.

I'd really appreciate some insight about exactly why this doesn't work and requires the lambda version to be used.

Comment: Do a small experiment, put a `console.log(this)` inside the `setTimeout`, that should print different output when you use the arrow notation than when you don't use it.

Comment: `setTimeout(this.runTask.bind(this), 0)`

Comment: @Barmar That does seem to do the trick. But...

How is it that a method on a class instance could lose its definition of `this`? I think I'm maybe bringing C++ baggage with me and being confused about how one could call a method on a class instance *without* having a valid `this` and needing to specify it. What's special about passing that method along that requires `bind` to be called like this?

Comment: @SebastianSimon That does seem to touch on similar issues, but I wouldn't have expected this behaviour within a class instance. Since my `this` context does seem incorrect here, what `this` is being used in the `go()` version?

Comment: `this` is only assigned when the method is *called*, not when it's referenced in other ways.

Comment: @Barmar So without the bind, what is `this` referring to in this case?

Comment: It gets the global object, i.e. `window` in a browser.

Comment: @aar The behavior is unrelated to classes. `this` is `undefined` in strict mode or `globalThis` in loose mode when passed as a callback, unbound. Note that passing something as a parameter assigns it to the argument of the function which accepts the callback (`setTimeout` in this case). Since passing a parameter is a form of assignment, `const runTask = this.runTask; setTimeout(runTask);` would have the same result, but already at `const runTask`. (Note this other [linked question](/q/30486345/4642212)). See [How does the "this" keyword work?](/q/3127429/4642212), which explains everything.

Comment: OK, I think that makes sense. If you'd like to submit a formal answer I'd be happy to mark it as solved. Thank you!

Comment: @SebastianSimon You had provided [an earlier link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback) which I think covered some of this material well. My concern with closing the question is that I would never have searched for the phrase 'How does the "this" keyword work?" in order to solve this particular issue.

Comment: @aardvarkk _“I would never have searched for …”_ — Yes, I know that this is unfortunate… That’s why the duplicate target has [2,529 linked questions](/questions/linked/20279484). As [the fourth most linked JS question](/questions/tagged/javascript?tab=Frequent), it’s one of the most common issues that JS devs stumble upon sooner or later. On the other hand, reading the most frequent questions in this list is a great way to learn about the pitfalls of a language early.